# Visual Basic Including Two TextBox.Text Together in MessageBox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I don't know how to put it, I'm using Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2013 Windows Form Application, but I have 2 textbox, both of them are for String data.

1) nameTxt
2) birthTxt

When the user click a button, the button will run this messagebox code:

```
MessageBox.Show(nametxt.Text)
```

But the question is, I want it to show both nameTxt and birthTxt plus some text as some line like this:

"Hello *nametxt.Text*! Oh, you're from *birthTxt.text*. Nice to meet you!"

I know in C++, you can make a cout like this:

```
cout << "Hello " << nameTxt << ". Oh, you're from " << birthTxt << ". Nice to meet you";
```

Anyone can help me? I'm new with visual basic, and I dont know to ask specific question for this.

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(nametxt.Text & birthTxt.Text)`

Comment: Ok, but how do I make it inline like this "Hello *nametxt.Text*, you're from *birthTxt.text". I'm confused on this one.

Comment: "Hello " & nametxt.Text ...

Comment: Oh thanks, I've found it. MessageBox.Show("Hello " & nameTxt.Text & ". You're from" & birthTxt.text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Msgbox("Hello " & nametxt.Text &"! Oh, you're from " &  birthTxt.text & ". Nice to meet you!")
```